# Can I customize file names or add labels in the documentDirectory for Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with audio files in a `documentDirectory`, and they are currently saved from a remote URL to the directory.

For a new feature, I want the user to be able to delete those files. I am doing that successfully, but I am having trouble making this readable for the user.

For instance, using the directory, I can make a string of the "file name" like I do here in `thedownloads` variable; however, it produces a file name like `e8213375-917e-482a-8ba4-f58a298d8bf1` that won't help the user figure out which audio file they are deleting.

I read the documentation on `documentDirectory` but didn't see anything -- is there any way to add something like a label to each document in the directory that I can call here (for instance, if each file name could also be called "Track 1", "Track 2" in the cell)?

```
class DownloadTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var thedownloads = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get the document directory url
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    do {
        // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        // print(directoryContents)        

        // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
        let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
        //print("mp3 urls:",mp3Files)
        let mp3FileNames = mp3Files.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
        //print("mp3 list:", mp3FileNames)

        thedownloads = mp3FileNames

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    print(thedownloads)
```

Comment: You can use the `FileManager`'s `moveItem` methods to rename files.

Comment: You should just prompt the user to rename the file when finished downloading it or provide a way to rename it (as mentioned above) just move it to the same folder with a different name (lastPathComponent)

Comment: So I would ideally like to name the file to something readable when the user first reaches the table. Do you think the answer is for me to rename files when they are first downloaded then?